# GridView - Images,Text and ItemClick

Tags: android, listview, gridview

my friends
I am a new in android and I wanted to do an example (code) like the picture
GridView - Images,Text and ItemClick
Thanks to all[image]

Comment: You should start to looking for online tutorial ... question is too broad for SO

Comment: Go on Fiverr and pay someone to make it for you

Comment: Don't go on fiverr and let someone do it for you, they will do it in the easiest quickest way without taking in account future issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for RecyclerView. Create a layout and add recyclerView to it then create another layout file for the rows of the recyclerview as below:

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Create another layout row_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity, add following lines of code:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, false);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

After this, create an Adapter according to your specific need for the recyclerView which can be found with a quick google search. Just remmeber to infalte your row_layout in the adapter's onCreateViewHolder. After creating the adapter just set it to your recyclerView.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(your_custom_adapter);
```

This is just a gist of what you ought to do. It'll get you started in the right direction. The rest is just a search away.